# Mangled folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

WinMerge (invoked from within Dreamweaver) appears occasionally to mangle Windows directories.

Trying to access the _compareTemp folder WinMerge creates using Windows Explorer just shows “Access is denied”, and I can’t delete the folder.

Looking at it more closely with a Command Prompt, I see that instead of the ‘.’ and ‘..’ directories which an empty folder normally contains, this one just contains ‘_compareTemp’, as if it contains itself.

If I reboot the machine, the problem seems to get resolved, but is there any way I can fix it without rebooting?

Comment: Are you sure your file-system isn't corrupt? Does chkdsk notice any problems?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to be having that problem because Dreamweaver still has a lock on the _comapreTemp folder.

You can try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to remove all open handles to the folder after which you should be able to delete the folder.

Download Unlocker from http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ or [FileHippo.com](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/).